# Centrar un dropdown con Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Estoy armando un `dropdown` dentro de un `card` con Bootstrap 4, el cual devuelve un `nav` con diferentes opciones.

La idea es que el "menú" del `dropdown` me quede en el medio, y solo he logrado que vaya a la izquierda o la derecha.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="card text-center shadow">
    <div class="card-header">
      (Título)
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Panel de información</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Elija la información que desee ver en los paneles de información.</p>
      <p>
        <div class="dropup">
          <a class="text-dark" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-plus-circle"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle><line x1="12" y1="8" x2="12" y2="16"></line><line x1="8" y1="12" x2="16" y2="12"></line></svg>
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Active</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </p>

    </div>
    <div class="card-footer text-muted">
      (Acciones)
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Intentaste usar flex-box de Bootstrap. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/

Comment: Intenta agregar dentro de la clase `dropdown-menu show` las siguientes propiedades `left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, 0);` y nos cuentas cómo te va con eso

Comment: No funciona. Probé con otro nombre para agregar desde otro archivo css y poner en el el class. desde el class "dropup", no pasa nada, pero desde la etiqueta <ul> me corre los íconos, pero me deja el recuadro a la derecha. (No se si se entiende)

Comment: Seguro que no funciona? Lo estoy haciendo justo aquí en el snippet y veo que se centra el dropup. Solo agrega esto en la sección de CSS y verás `.dropdown-menu.show {
  left: 50%!important;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0)!important;
}`. No deberías usar la regla important, lo hago solo porque no tengo acceso a tu CSS, la idea es reemplazarlo y no sobrescribirlo.

Comment: Funciona! el único problema es que al agregar más <li> me tapa el simbolo de plus-circle, y el drop se me va para abajo...Además, funciona sin la palabra show, solo el class .dropdown-menu... Gracias!, seguiré probando